# Share ArcGIS Field Map projects with student

Tags: arcgis-field-maps

I am searching for an efficient way to share generic (point/line/polygon) ArcGIS Field Map projects with students...

We are transitioning our GPS data collection to ArcGIS Field maps.  I am trying to figure out an efficient way for students to transfer a Field Map project I have stored in my ArcGIS Online account to their AGOL account (each student has an ArcGIS Online account of their own).  I want to ensure that the data they collect is stored in their AGOL account, not mine.

What advice do you have for managing multiple users in this situation?